# How is it possible for Brave Android Browser to read and write to internal storage for Android 10?

Tags: android, android-10.0, android-storage

I am using Download Manager to download files to user's phone. 
If I set `setExternalPublicStorageDir(Directory.Downloads)` the file will appear in gallery.

I will however have no access to it later as `getExternalPublicStorage` is deprecated in Android 10. I would like access to determine if the file is already downloaded.

I saw that Brave browser asks you for download location and that it is able to tell you if you have already downloaded the file. How is this possible? 
[image]

Comment: They are probably using `MediaStore.Downloads`: https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/01/11/scoped-storage-stories-diabolical-details-downloads.html

Comment: Is there an example of how to use the MediaStore.Downloads to download a file to an external file then how to check if that file is already downloaded @CommonsWare

Comment: The blog post that I linked to covers that.

Comment: I tested the app listed in the blog and I was unable to view the downloaded files in gallery @CommonsWare

Comment: You can view the content that you download. You cannot view content downloaded by other apps. This is covered in the blog post.

Comment: @CommonsWare I tested your app with a jpg and that is correct. Thank you. One final question. Why is it necessary to write to the `From there, we use Okio to slurp down video content and stream it out to the, um, stream. ` If I am using DownloadManager the file is already downloaded. But if I understand correctly. I will only need to add it to the MediaStore correct? I am confused if I also need to create a file and write the outputstream to it.

Comment: "If I am using DownloadManager the file is already downloaded" -- my sample app does not. It uses OkHttp and Okio to download the content directly. "But if I understand correctly. I will only need to add it to the MediaStore correct?" -- I have not used `DownloadManager` in years, so I do not know what is required for using it on Android 10, sorry.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you for that. Why is the MediaStore necessary in that case? I feel I dont fully understand it. I see that it has a collection of Images,Videos and such but why do we need to insert to it. Is it different than using `getExternalPublicStorageDirectory` and saving the file?

Comment: "Is it different than using getExternalPublicStorageDirectory and saving the file?" -- yes. On Android 10 and higher, you do not have access to that directory anymore. You might want to read [this](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/06/07/death-external-storage-end-saga.html), followed by the series of blog posts starting with [this](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/19/scoped-storage-stories-saf-basics.html), for more background on the changes and your options.